# Alternative to multiple constructors

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-room

I have this constructor...

```
public ShiftLog(String companyName, boolean workedForAgent, String agentName,
                    Date shiftStart, Date shiftEnd,
                    boolean breakTaken, Date breakStart,
                    Date breakEnd, boolean isTransportJob,
                    String transportCompanyName, String vehicleRegistration) {
        this.userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.workedForAgent = workedForAgent;
        this.agentName = agentName;
        this.shiftStart = shiftStart;
        this.shiftEnd = shiftEnd;
        this.breakTaken = breakTaken;
        this.breakStart = breakStart;
        this.breakEnd = breakEnd;
        this.isTransportJob = isTransportJob;
        this.transportCompanyName = transportCompanyName;
        this.vehicleRegistration = vehicleRegistration;
    }
```

Now I want to add in a shift log (instantiate a shift log object for a user). The problem is that there are multiple combinations a shift log can have. For example, `workedForAgent` is false, there should be no need to pass in `agentName`. How can I do that without creating multiple constructors because there can be multiple possible combinations? For example, user can work for agent but not take a break, meaning break start time and end time shouldn't be needed to pass in. But that would require so many constructors for all possible combinations. Any alternative?

Also I am using the room database to append all this info. So if `workedForAgent` is false for example, automatically set `agentName` to null. How could that be done as well.

Comment: Hey there! In my opinion having different constructors would be the best way, allowing you to immediately understand what you are going to do with each one. An alternative could be having a factory of objects with static methods explaining what they do with the objects.
Having a single constructor will force you to remind the different combinations of arguments.

Comment: You could reduce the arguments to a minium that is used for every Shift. Then set the rest of the variables via setters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Builder patterns](https://medium.com/@ajinkyabadve/builder-design-patterns-in-java-1ffb12648850).

> Builder pattern is a creational design pattern it means its solves problem related to object creation.
>
> It typically solve problem in object oriented programming i.e determining what constructor to use.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Kodiak 
You can replace your constructor with builder in few clicks
as mentioned here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/replace-constructor-with-builder.html

Plus, the best part is,it will refactor all the occurrence of the constructor with builder automatically

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** Use Getters/Setters

**Long Answer:** The alternative method here is that you can instantiate the variables that you sure they must exist in the constructor and then the other conditional variables can be defined with setter methods and you can easily fetch with getters.

```
public class ShiftLog {

    private Object userUid;
    private String companyName;
    private boolean workedForAgent;
    private String agentName;
    private Date shiftStart;
    private Date shiftEnd;
    private boolean breakTaken;
    private Date breakStart;
    private Date breakEnd;
    private boolean isTransportJob;
    private String transportCompanyName;
    private String vehicleRegistration;

    public ShiftLog(String companyName, Date shiftStart, Date shiftEnd) {

        this.userUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.shiftStart = shiftStart;
        this.shiftEnd = shiftEnd;

    }

    public boolean isWorkedForAgent() {
        return workedForAgent;
    }

    public void setWorkedForAgent(boolean workedForAgent) {
        this.workedForAgent = workedForAgent;
    }

    public String getAgentName() {
        return agentName;
    }

    public void setAgentName(String agentName) {
        this.agentName = agentName;
    }

    public boolean isBreakTaken() {
        return breakTaken;
    }

    public void setBreakTaken(boolean breakTaken) {
        this.breakTaken = breakTaken;
    }

    public Date getBreakStart() {
        return breakStart;
    }

    public void setBreakStart(Date breakStart) {
        this.breakStart = breakStart;
    }

    public Date getBreakEnd() {
        return breakEnd;
    }

    public void setBreakEnd(Date breakEnd) {
        this.breakEnd = breakEnd;
    }

    public boolean isTransportJob() {
        return isTransportJob;
    }

    public void setTransportJob(boolean isTransportJob) {
        this.isTransportJob = isTransportJob;
    }

    public String getTransportCompanyName() {
        return transportCompanyName;
    }

    public void setTransportCompanyName(String transportCompanyName) {
        this.transportCompanyName = transportCompanyName;
    }

    public String getVehicleRegistration() {
        return vehicleRegistration;
    }

    public void setVehicleRegistration(String vehicleRegistration) {
        this.vehicleRegistration = vehicleRegistration;
    }
}
```